# Is there any software on Windows that can simulate the Android desktop?

Tags: windows, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Organize desktop icons on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/14835/organize-desktop-icons-on-windows)

I have a lot of software that belong in different categories, such as; programming, design, electrical engineering, etc.

I would like to split up the shortcuts on different desktops similar to the Android style.

Is there any software on Windows that can do this job?

Comment: Have you looked into VirtualBox + Android x86?

Comment: @kobaltz The idea here is to have "pages" of icons on the desktop. Jinchao is just using Android as an example. The title does not currently reflect the question well.

Comment: @iglvzx: your are right, i am looking for that kind of software.