# A way to organize desktop icons?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons, fences

I have already looked at Fences from another SuperUser [post](https://superuser.com/questions/14835/organize-desktop-icons-on-windows-into-categories-or-sections), but it doesn't really fit what I am looking for. I have noticed that some laptops (I am a desktop user) come bundled with little toolbar-like things that can latch on to the top of the desktop, or a side. One thing I don't really like about Fences is that there is the gap between the edge of the screen and the actual Fence, which kind is kind of frustrating to me.

So basically, I want an organization method similar to Fences, but that latches onto the top of the screen, and that I can have more control over its size. I would also like for it to not span across the entire width of the desktop, only 4-6 inches, or however long I would like it to be. It would be great if I could also add sidebars with the icons facing down as well. I know they have these for laptops, but I couldn't figure out how to find them online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/) is pretty customizable with regard to size, position, and distance from edge.